# Socket disconnection issue and polling

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, polling

I have developed one chat application using socket and node js , in start it works perfectly but i have observed that after some interval of time there is one polling error thrown and than socket disconnects.

Error screenshot : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RWAoqHmpRSR1RkNvE1-XsFtVIvBX24bY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It disconnects and reconnect automatically again and again or remains disconnected

Comment: Its reconnects automatically.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This might fix the issue:

Add this line on server.js:

```
io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
```

Add this on client.js:

```
var socket = io('/',{transports: ['websocket'],upgrade:false});
```

And do one more thing just use lower socket.io version like 2.0.3

Comment: show your code here so that i can see it and then it would be easier to find out problem